# Is there some way to get the values of array checked and compared with something inside checkWinningMoves()

Tags: javascript

How can I see if the array movesByX has the values but is not in the order  as displayed in the checkWinningMoves fucntion how can make sure it works properly and executes the function

```js
function checkWinningMoves() {
   if (movesByX == ["box1", "box2", "box3"]) {
       console.log("X is the winner")
   }
}
let movesByX = [ "box2", "box1", "box3"]

checkWinningMoves();
```

Comment: You can't compare arrays this way, equality is evaluated by reference, not shape/value. see: [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Function, that will check if all the winning moves are present in `movesByX` irrespective of order. It uses a `for` loop, and array's `includes` method, that checks if an element is present in array or not.

```js
function checkWinningMoves() {
  if (checkElem(movesByX)) {
    console.log("X is the winner")
  } else{
    console.log("X is not the winner");
  }
}

let movesByX = ["box2", "box1", "box3"]
checkWinningMoves();

movesByX = ["box2", "box4", "box3"]
checkWinningMoves();


function checkElem(arr) {
  let a = ["box1", "box2", "box3"];
  let out = false;

  for(var i = 0;i<a.length; i++){
    if(arr.includes(a[i])){
      out = true;
    } else{
      out = false;
      break;
    }
  }
    return out;
  }
```